# Can you use Anonymous Access on Host Named Site Collections in a Claims Based Web Application?

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, anonymous-authentication, host-named

We have a Claims Based Web Application which hosts various Host Named Site Collections.

One of these sites requires Anonymous Access. I have applied AA to the Web Application and activated it on the Site Collection in question. However, when users log in, when they navigate to another page they lose their login credentials (as if the cookies arent holding their data). Then they browse as Anonymous Users but suddenly they will appear logged in again?

Is this an error or a known issue? Can you use Anonymous Access on Claims Based Host Named Site Collections? Is their anything I can do to stop logged in users from suddenly being logged out and in?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Does the anon/logged in switch when staying in the same web app? Is it ever switching logged in => anon when in the same web app? If so are there multiple Web Front End Servers?